# Adding certain number of rows at once with a short code

Tags: tables, tabularx, rows

I know how to add an amount of columns with a shortcut below;

```
\begin{table}[t]
\centerline{
\begin{tabularx}{1.25\linewidth}{|c|*{12}{X|}}
\hline
\# & JAN & FEB & MARCH & APRIL & MAY & JUNE & JULY & AUG & SEP & OCT & NOV & DEC\\
\hline
1 & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
2 & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline 
\end{tabularx}
    }
\end{table}
```

But I am not sure how do you do the same to add, for instance, 31 rows into a table.